# Why can't I place a bounty on a question with an expired bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314269/android-app-users-get-installation-unsuccessful-after-introducing-iab?answertab=active#tab-top) that had a serious need for attention, so I placed a bounty on it. The question received attention but nobody could come up with a concrete solution, therefore I did not grant anyone the bounty and it expired. Now  I want to place a bounty once more to get another attempt at finding a good answer, but instead of the "place a bounty" button, I get "eligible for bounty since 2 Apr", and when I click it, it redirects me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) page.

[image]

Why is this? I have the normal button on other questions and can seemingly place bounties as normal. Can you not place more than 1 bounty on a single question?